# Extract file written by application from internal memory

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y. My application writes log file to sd card for every server transaction. If sd card is not present I'm writing my log file to internal memory. Now my problem is, how can I extract the log file written to internal memory physically (like by connecting to usb will not work if sd card is not present).So how do I see if the file is written. I can see it in my emulator in /data/data/apppkg/files/log.txt but on physical device i'm unable to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a good reason, the physical device will not allow you to access internal memory without root privileges.

If you want to make sure you can reliably get these logs, email them to yourself (easily with an email intent & data) or put them in your respective app directory on external storage.